# What does this shader code return for two vectors a, b, given an angle of 45 degrees between them?

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl

What is the value returned by:

```
dot(normalize(a), normalize(b))
```

given that the angle between the vectors a and b is 45°.

- 0
- 1
- sqrt(2)
- 1 / sqrt(2)

Comment: Please clarify your question: what are the values of a and b, what is the result of the dot product ?

Comment: I don't have values of a and b but their angle is 45 degree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general The *dot* product of 2 vectors is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors multiplied by the magnitude (length) of both vectors.

```
dot( A, B ) == | A | * | B | * cos( angle_A_B )
```

This follows, that the *dot* product of 2 unit vectors is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors, because the length of a unit vector is 1.

```
uA = normalize( A )
uB = normalize( B )
cos( angle_A_B ) == dot( uA, uB )
```

[image: A dot B]

---

This means that, if the angle between a vector `a` and `b` is 45 degrees, then:

```
dot(normalize(a), normalize(b))  =  cos(45°)  =  1 / sqrt(2)
```

Note, the length of the diagonal in a square with a side length of *1*, is *sqrt(2)*. If the lenght of the diagonal is *1*, then the length of one side is *1 / sqrt(2)*.